# Как реализовать много-столбцовый вывод файлов в консоль, как в утилите ls?

Tags: linux, c, macos, unix, ls

Мне нужно реализовать функционал утилиты ls с помощью языка C. Нужно повторить все точь в точь, как и в оригинальной **ls**. И проблема, которую я не могу решить - это многостолбцовый вывод.
В оригинальном **ls** по дефолту все содержимое выводится в несколько столбцов, примерно вот *так*:\

*dir1 file1 file2 dir2

dir3 file3 file4 dir4*

Но при использовании **ls | cat -e**, оказывается, что после каждого выводимого файла находится символ конца строки. Вот так:

dir1$
file1$
file2$
dir2$
...

Вопрос в том, как же все таки этот вывод работает в оригинальном ls, и как можна было бы его реализовать с помощью C? Спасибо.

Comment: За 2 прохода по списку файлов. На первом определяете ширину каждого столбца (зависит од длины имени файла). На втором заполняете выводную строку (все столбцы) и печатаете ее

Comment: @avp спасибо за ответ, но все же, как все таки ls выводит все в несколько колонок, а ls | cat -e показывает, что каждый файл выведен с новой строки?

Comment: Как работает - можно глянуть в исходниках ls, например http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/bin/ls/ls.c?rev=1.67&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup

Comment: Для начала, ls смотрит он выводит в терминал (и тогда по умолчанию делает несколько колонок) или нет (в этом случае колонка одна, но если вызвать ls -C, то и тут он выведет в несколтко колонок). Думаю, в man ls все это должно быть написано

Comment: @avp Спасибо большое! Я даже и не подумал об этом